# Nested GPath expressions with XmlSlurper and findAll

Tags: groovy, xmlslurper, gpath

I'm trying to analyse an XML tree using `XmlSlurper` and GPath, and the behaviour of the `findAll` method confuses me.

Say, for example, that you have the following XML tree:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li class="odd"><span>Element 1</span></li>
            <li class="even"><span>Element 2</span></li>
            <li class="odd"><span>Element 3</span></li>
            <li class="even"><span>Element 4</span></li>
            <li class="odd"><span>Element 5</span></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Assuming that `xml` has been initialised through one of `XmlSlurper`'s `parse` methods, the following code executes as one would expect:

```
// Prints:
// odd
// odd
// odd
xml.body.ul.li.findAll {it.@class == 'odd'}.@class.each {println it.text()}
```

On the other hand:

```
// Doesn't print anything.
xml.body.ul.li.findAll {it.@class == 'odd'}.span.each {println it.text()}
```

I'm struggling to understand why I can use the special `@` property (as well as others, such as `**`), but not 'normal' ones.

I've looked at the API code, and what confuses me even more is that the `getProperty` implementation (found in `GPathResult`) seems to support what I'm trying to do.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to iterate over every `span`, so you can use the spread-dot operator:

```
xml.body.ul.li.findAll {it.@class == 'odd'}*.span.each {println it.text()}
```

Comment: +1 for the spread-dot operator, it solves the specific problem nicely! It doesn't explain the difference of behaviour between the `@class` property and the `span` one though, or am I missing something?

Comment: @NicolasRinaudo Not 100% sure, and delving into the code hasn't helped massively. `.@class` follows [a different path](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/subprojects/groovy-xml/src/main/java/groovy/util/slurpersupport/GPathResult.java#L124) to just [accessing the property](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/subprojects/groovy-xml/src/main/java/groovy/util/slurpersupport/GPathResult.java#L136) though... it's as if something is missing from FilteredNodeList... I'll investigate some more when I get time...

Comment: thanks for the time you're sinking into this. I'm reaching the same conclusion myself - [this](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/subprojects/groovy-xml/src/main/java/groovy/util/slurpersupport/GPathResult.java#L136) looks like it's meant to support the `.span` call, but doesn't seem to work. I'd probably file a bug report if it was a language I felt more confident with, but Groovy has a tendency to not behave the way I expect it to in a perfectly logical and correct fashion.

Comment: @NicolasRinaudo I think this bug is the same thing, so hopefully it will be fixed soon https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-6122